# Attempting to insert data into a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `design_designs`
The table contains 4 columns: `id, key, value, nonceId`

I'm attempting to run a query to insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO design_designs(key, value, nonceId)
VALUES ('test key', 'test value', 'test nonce');
```

The error i get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, value, nonceId)
VALUES ('test key', 'test value', 'test nonce')' at line 1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? According to the documentation on queries my query is correct.  I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word, you must delimit it:

```
INSERT INTO design_designs(`key`, value, nonceId) VALUES...
```